# Proof for the fact that [0,1] or any interval [a,b] in $\mathbb{R}$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I found a proof for the fact that any interval [a,b] is connected in $\mathbb{R}$ can somebody check if it is correct.
Suppose that if it is not connected then $\exists$ two closed sets U and V such that they are disjoint and non empty and  their union is [a,b] now since they are disjoint and non empty consider distinct points $u_{0}$ in U and $v_{0}$ in V now construct the sequences $\{u_{n}\}$ and $\{v_{n}\}$ as follows $m =\frac{u_{i} +v_{i}}{2}$ if m $\epsilon$ U then $u_{i+1} = m$ , $v_{i+1}=v_i$ else if m belongs to V then $v_{i+1} =m$ , $u_{i+1}=u_{i}$ now we get sequences $\{u_{n}\}$  and $\{v_{n}\}$ both converge to the same value c now since c is a limit point for both U and V implies c belongs to both U and V (bcoz U and V are both closed ). Hence contradiction because we assumed them to be disjoint.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: One should probably write the justification that $\{u_n\}$ and $\{v_n\}$ both converge and converge to the same value. Otherwise, nice job!

Comment: @GregMartin Thanx ! I didn't wrote the prove for that because  of my laziness and also because it was quite obvious as the sequence $|u_{n}-v_{n}|$ converges to zero

Comment: You might also be interested in the result that the connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with usual topology are precisely the singletons and intervals.

Comment: @RishavGupta first of all it isn't obvious to me why $|u_n-v_n|$ converges to zero. Secondly that doesn't imply that they both converge and to the same limit. In fact for any sequence $x_n$, convergent or not, we have $|x_n-x_n|=0$ converges to $0$. Generally $|x_n-y_n|$ converging to zero implies only that both sequences have the same cluster points: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173875/if-the-difference-of-two-sequence-converge-to-zero-then-both-sequences-must-hav

Comment: @freakish Again sorry for my laziness , u re right its not obvious i was just justifying my laziness , I am not implying that $|u_{n}−v_{n}|$ converges to zero implies $u_{n}$ and $v_{n}$ are convergent , to prove that they are convergent we need to show that they are Cauchy for that we will use $|u_{n+1}-u_{n}|$ = $0$ or $\frac{|u_{0}-v_{0}|}{2^{n+1}}$ using this fact along with triangle inequality we can show that $u_{n}$ similarly $v_{n}$ are cauchy hence also convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof relies on the metric and some arithmetic on $[0,1]$. Topologists like to go basic and in this case we can use that $[0,1]$ (or the homeomorphic $[a,b], a < b$) have the order topology and are nice:

Some general theory:

Let $X$ be an ordered topological space $(X,<)$, so the topology is generated by the subbase $\{(\leftarrow,x),(x,\rightarrow)\mid x \in X\}$

**Definition**: A cut $(A,B)$ of $X$ (by which I mean $A,B \subseteq X$, both non-empty, $A \cap B = \emptyset$, $A \cup B = X$, and also for all $a \in B$ and all $b \in B$ we have $a < b$) is called a **jump** if $A$ has a maximum *and* $B$ has a minimum, and a **gap** if neither is the case.

Theorems:

- $X$ is connected iff $X$ has no gaps or jumps.
- $X$ is compact iff it has no gaps, and a minimum and a maximum.

---

$[0,1]$ has no gaps as when $(A,B)$ is a cut of $[0,1]$, $\sup A$ is well-defined and if it lies in $A$, $A$ has a maximum, and if it lies in $B$, $B$ has a minimum. So no gap can exist.

Immediate corollary from the second theorem is that $[0,1]$ is compact (as $0=\min[0,1], 1= \max[0,1]$ also exist).

$[0,1]$ also has no jumps because between a supposed $\max A$ and $\min B$ we always have at least one rational which would be in neither $A$ not $B$ (by construction of $\Bbb R$ from $\Bbb Q$).

So the first theorem then implies $[0,1]$ is connected.

These theorem have a lot more applications than just the intervals in $\Bbb R$, and also apply to lexicographically ordered squares and ordinal spaces etc. So it's quite useful to have these general criteria.

My alma mater had quite a few specialists on ordered spaces so these theorems were standard fare in our topology diet as students. Nowadays not many texts cover them any more, alas.